# Error in Parse in R: No such file or directory error

Tags: r, string, parsing

Let's suppose I have the following dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
colnames(df1) <- c("mpg","cyl")
df2 <- data.frame(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$cyl)
colnames(df2) <- c("qsec","cyl")
```

And I do an index of these two objects.

```
idx <- objects()
```

Now I can easily call `df1$cyl` and it will return a vector, which is what is expected, it shows in the console and is fine.

```
> df1$cyl
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

Now imagine I want to use `parse` command because I want to do the same thing out of a string:

```
cname = "cyl"
parse(sprintf('%s$%s', idx[1], came))
```

Surprisingly, it returns a `No such file or directory` error:

```
> parse(sprintf('%s$%s', idx[1], cname))
Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r") :
  cannot open file 'df1$cyl': No such file or directory
```

I make sure ´´´sprintf('%s$%s', idx[1], cname)´´´ reads `"df1$cyl"` so I can make sure `parse` commnad simply executes it.

```
> sprintf('%s$%s', idx[1], cname)
[1] "df1$cyl"
```

Any ideas of why is this happening? Is this expected behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: I have never used only `parse` but you can get your expected output with `eval(parse(text = sprintf('%s$%s', idx[1], cname)))`. If you explain why you want to do this there might be better approach to handle this.

Comment: Instead of `parse(..., text=...)` you can also use `str2expression(...)` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `parse` you need to use the `text` argument:

```r
eval(parse(text=sprintf('%s$%s', idx[1], cname)))
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

But you can achieve the same with

```r
get(idx[1])[[cname]]
```

However, in cases like this it is usually better to store your data frames in a list rather than in the global environment:

```r
dfs <- list(df1 = data.frame(mpg = mtcars$mpg, cyl = mtcars$cyl),
            df2 = data.frame(qsec = mtcars$mpg, cyl = mtcars$cyl))
```

and then you can do

```r
dfs[[1]][[cname]]
```